# How to traverse Rtree 0.6.0 in Python

Tags: python, traversal, r-tree

Does anyone know how to traverse the whole tree in [this Python Rtree library](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Rtree/)?

I've checked all its methods but failed to find a interface for this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Do an `intersection()` query with the input parameters being those returned by `bounds()`? By definition everything in the index will intersect with a space equal to the bounds of the index.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to accomplish this, started to create a new thread for this and stackoverflow suggested me this thread instead.

For anyone stumbling across the same, I got ya.

Here is my working code.

```
import rtree
from random import random


rands =[random() for i in range(100)]

def generator_function():
    for i, coord in enumerate(rands):
        yield(i, (coord, coord+1, coord, coord+1), coord)

rtree = rtree.index.Index(generator_function())

for point in rtree.intersection(rtree.bounds):
    print(point)
```